# Scripts not loading when using the wp_enqueue_scripts action

Tags: functions, actions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, scripts

Really basic, I'm afraid. My scripts aren't loading when I put them as part of a function triggered by the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action in `functions.php`. If I put them outside of that action as part of the main file, they load fine, but of course this is bad form. So:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'intranet-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

works but throws up errors in debugging but

```
function intranet_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'intranet-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'intranet_scripts' );
```

does nothing, it doesn't even throw up any errors. I must be missing something super basic but I can't for the life of me see what it is. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_stylesheet_uri()` loads the **main stylesheet** of the theme. If you need to load additional stylesheets, you need to use `get_template_directory_uri()` for parent themes and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` for child themes.

If you have stylesheet called `custom.css` in the root in a child theme, you will use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()' . /custom.css'`

You should also make sure that you have `wp_head()` inside your `<head></head>` tags in your header

Comment: It was the missing wp_head() that was doing it, thanks.